# Matlab index matrix by vector specifying column

Tags: matlab, indexing

Let `A` be of size `[n,m]`, i.e. it has `n` rows and `m` columns. Given `I` of size `[n,1]` with `max(I)<=m`, what is the fastest way to return `B` of size `[n,1]`, such that `B(i)=A(i,I(i))`?

Example:

```
A =
 8     1     6
 3     5     7
 4     9     2
```

and

```
I =
 1
 2
 2
```

I want `B` to look like

```
B =
 8
 5
 9
```

There obviously exist several ways to implement this, but in my case `n` is in the order of `1e6` and `m` in the order of `1e2`, which is why I'm interested in the fastest implementation. I would like to avoid `ind2sub` or `sub2ind` since they both appear to be too slow as well. Any idea is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Well, its either `sub2ind` or looping

Answer (score 2):

You can replicate the behavior of `sub2ind` yourself. This gives me a speedup in my test:

```
clear

%% small example
A = rand(4,6)
I = [3 2 2 1]

inds = (I-1)*size(A,1) + (1:length(I));
B = A(inds)

%% timing
n = 1e4;
m = 1e2;
A = rand(n, m);
I = ceil(rand(1,n) * m);

% sub2ind
F = @() A(sub2ind(size(A), 1:size(A,1), I));
timeit(F)

% manual
F = @() A((I-1)*size(A,1) + (1:length(I)));
timeit(F)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
 A(meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1)) == repmat(I,1,size(A,2)))
```

which will give you the same result, with no loop and no `sub2ind`.